# The iframe is loading everywhere except in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have an iframe that users embed on their website. It's working fine on other websites, but a new user wants to put it inside his Chrome extension and is encountering the following error:

"Refused to frame 'https://www.example.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 'frame-ancestors *'. Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. The scheme 'https:' must be added explicitly."

Currently the CSP header looks like this

[image]

Initially, I had the same error when embedding it on other websites. So, I made changes to the code in the backend (Content-Security Plolicy related) to make it embeddable on all pages, which is now working fine on websites. However, it is not working in the Chrome extension.

Does it require additional CSP rules to work in the Chrome extension?

Comment: What is your current CSP header for the iframe? You can verify it in devtools' network panel.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have added a screenshot of CSP above

Comment: Looks like your CSP header is superfluous. You can remove it entirely and the site will be embeddable everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The source * in CSP doesn't mean allow everything. As the error message says, it only allows everything from certain schemes. Chrome extensions are likely not treated as being one of those schemes. The simple solution is to remove the frame-ancestors directive from your CSP is it doesn't really do anything but block Chrome extensions.